# In Eclipse how to make local tomcat server republish WITHOUT Eclipse being in the foreground

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, filesystemwatcher

I am developing a Java/JSP/Javascript web app using Eclipse Oxygen and its local Tomcat 8.5 server fairly with the standard config:

[image]

This works excellently if I do *all* work in Eclipse: On each resource change everything is republished. Great!

However the JavaScript part I want to develop in another IDE (WebStorm) which uses the same source directory as Eclipse. When I save a file from the external IDE, Tomcat does pick up the resource change *only* if I bring Eclipse to the foreground. This is cumbersome.

How can I configure the Eclipse Tomcat Server to either:

- republish *periodically* (regardless of resource changes)

or

- republish *on file system resource changes*, not Eclipse resource changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by editing the workspace preferences:

Navigate to `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace` and activate the following checkboxes:

- `Refresh using native hooks or polling`
- `Refresh on access`

This should (with a delay of some seconds) refresh, build and deploy resources when changed by a foreign application.